# SQL Server - Displaying >= a different way on a report

Tags: sql-server, formatting, report, ascii

I have a user who wants to show quality spec descriptions where the >= shows as an underlined > instead of having the = sign to the right. In SQL server, I cannot find a way to do this and I don't think there is an ASCII code for this. I know this is an obscure one but I thought I would ask the question.

Thanks,
Maria

Here is more information and an image of what is being asked for.

I wrote a SQL stored procedure that is executed by an SSRS report. The grid that is returned from this proc contains a formatted criteria column. The users want to see Less Than Or Equal To as a left carrot underlined. All in one space and not like this <=.  In Excel and Word you can do this because you can just use < and then underline it.  But in SQL, I can't do this. I cannot add the underline in SSRS because the column is a big long text string and it's variable. I've convinced the users to forget this.  I told them that some things they have done in Word and Excel can't be done on this type of automated report.  Short of using the ascii character of < and the ascii character for _ and then making sure they are on top of each other by preventing a space seems way too complicated when they can just get used to seeing <=  or >= .  Let me know if you agree and thanks for the input.

Thanks for the reply to my post.

Comment: Is this issue SQL related or report related? Seems like you are trying to display a text on a report and facing issues? Could you pls elaborate with report name, tools you are using, any progress made etc.?

Comment: Hi Koushik. Thanks for the reply. I've added more detail to my post.